In philosophy as a whole, what keeps you interested and do you have ways to avoid existentialism
I think asking questions is basic human nature, we are always learning and growing as a population and a species. Philosophy is intriguing and I am sure everyone on this platform likes asking questions. How do others not turn to nihilism or absurdism? And do others ever get tired of questions not being answered?
Philosophy can be taxing on the mind and lead to constant dread and uncomfortable curiosity.
Do you have anyone to relate to in the real world with such topics or do they get bored, do you feel you can't relate with them? This may not be a question about an actual philosophical idea but I feel anything can be if you think about it hard enough and I simply want some other's opinions and maybe some insight, Thank you.

You use "existentialism" in the title; "nihilism + absurdism" in the body. If you want to suggest that existentialism = nihilism + absurdism  you should say that

Maybe But I am not sure, I haven't thought about it that way, Thank you for the new perspective. I will take some time to think about that.

The close-vote itchy finger folks have already lined up 2 votes-to-close (VTC). I suggest until you have more clarity on what exactly you wish to ask, you delete the question yourself. You can still keep editing and more freely undelete it when it's ready[er]

To your question substance: Have you looked at Buddha, Lao Tzu through philosophical lenses ie not as religion figures. This is indirectly linked to you query ...have anyone to relate to...? Does this point to notable from philosophy or to live persons? The first is more philosophical though the 2nd may be more useful

Post this on https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/ and you'll get some feedback.
